# segment fault when passing right reference for literal in labmda with varidic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

the code is as follows

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int foo(int a){
    cout<<a;
    return a;
}

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
function<void()> wrapper( R f, Args&& ... args) {
    function<void()> fun([&] { f(forward<Args...>(args...)); });//crash
    //function<void()> fun=bind(f,forward<Args...>(args...));
    return fun;
}

int main(){
    auto d=wrapper(foo,1);
    d();
    return 0;
}
```

when I use bind, all is fine. but when I use lambda the program crash.
I wonder there is a way to capture variable by reference for lambda but capture literal by value(for efficiency)? Or should I stick with bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function<void()> fun([&] { f(forward<Args...>(args...)); });//crash
```

All of these captured objects, `f` and all `args`, are captured by reference.

All of them are parameters to `wrapper`.

But as soon as `wrapper` returns, all parameters to `wrapper` go out of scope and get destroyed. And your lambda's captured references, all of them, become dangling references.

I might see some wiggle room here, possibly, when `wrapper`'s parameters that ***could*** be references themselves, with the lambda then capturing a reference to the original object, and not the `wrapper` parameter itself.

But nothing guarantees that, here.

As such, this all but guarantees undefined behavior.

It is true that there is syntax to capture `f` by value, and everything else by reference, but this will not help you.

```
auto d=wrapper(foo,1);
```

Because even in this case, the one you're working with, your parameter is a prvalue, which will vanish in a puff of smoke when `wrapper` returns, leaving your lambda with an empty bag, holding a dangling reference.

You have no realistic options here except to capture ***everything*** by value.

Comment: Now I find that the segment fault is because I pass `f` by value, instead of capture literal by reference. When I pass `f` by right reference, my lambda work well, So I think that might be a solution?

Comment: I can't really tell you anything about some unseen code, a different version of the shown code. The only thing I can tell you is that, referencing the code that's shown in this question, after changing the lambda to capture by reference (and without `std::forward`), the shown code compiles and runs without errors.